# XCode installs debug apps on the 2nd page?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

This is really just a minor annoyance, but whenever I go to test a new project in the iPhone Simulator, the app gets installed on the 2nd page of the simulator's dashboard even though there's plenty of space on the first page.  Anyone happen to know why it does this, or if there's a way to get it to fill up that first page?

I'd like to keep my apps together so if I have to close and reopen different ones I don't have to page back and forth or spend time reorganizing the icons.

To reproduce, simply "Build and Debug" a new iphone or ipad project in XCode when you already have at least one app installed on the first page of the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode doesn't actually choose where the app goes; it's up to SpringBoard.app to decide where unplaced apps go. This happens on the phone too, with apps installed from the App Store (I know this because I have most things in folders, so there's still space left on the first page).

You could try sticking things in folders. I'm not sure what's preserved across simulator installs though...